# 302 redirect loop with nginx and Wordpress

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

I've been searching a couple of hours in Serverfault trying to solve this problem but I can not find a solution. What happens is:

I am having a 302 redirect loop using `wget` in my site, but not using the browser. In my nginx configuration I only have two *301* redirects, not *302*. I've tried to disable all the plugins from wordpress with no luck.

What could be causing the problem? Below is my nginx config. Some examples with `wget`:

```
wget elbauldelprogramador.com
    --2014-10-30 13:10:24--  http://elbauldelprogramador.com/
    Resolving elbauldelprogramador.com (elbauldelprogramador.com)... 
    Connecting to elbauldelprogramador.com (elbauldelprogramador.com)||:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
    Location: 404 [following]
    --2014-10-30 13:10:25--  http://elbauldelprogramador.com/404
    Reusing existing connection to elbauldelprogramador.com:80.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
    Location: 404 [following]
    --2014-10-30 13:10:25--  http://elbauldelprogramador.com/404
    Reusing existing connection to elbauldelprogramador.com:80.
    [...]
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
    Location: 404 [following]
    20 redirections exceeded.
```

And the logs in the server:

```
S.IP - - [30/Oct/2014:13:11:22 +0100] "GET /404 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
S.IP - - [30/Oct/2014:13:11:22 +0100] "GET /404 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
S.IP - - [30/Oct/2014:13:11:22 +0100] "GET /404 HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
```

#### Nginx config

```
server {
    #listen 127.0.0.1:81;
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
#    listen 127.0.0.1:81;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com 

    port_in_redirect off;
    server_tokens off;
    autoindex off;

    root /path;

    ## Page Speed Module ##
    include global/pagespeed.conf;

    ## Fastcgi cache start ##
    set $no_cache 0;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }

    # Deliver 404 instead of 403 "Forbidden"
    error_page 403 = 404;

    include global/restrictions.conf;
    include global/caching.conf;


    # Additional rules go here.
    access_log log/access.log;
    error_log log/error.log warn;

    rewrite ^/sitemap_index\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

    location = /p/guia-de-desarrollo-android.html {
        rewrite  /p/guia-de-desarrollo-android.html http://example.com/curso-programacion-android/ permanent;
    }

    location = /p/bases-de-datos.html {
        rewrite  /p/bases-de-datos.html http://example.com/bases-de-datos/ permanent;
    }

    location = /feeds/posts/default {
        rewrite /feeds/posts/default http://example.com/feed permanent;
    }

    location = /p/guias-gratuitas.html {
        rewrite /p/guias-gratuitas.html http://example.com/manuales-gratuitos/ permanent;
    }

    # Only include one of the files below.
    include global/wordpress.conf;
    include global/security.conf;

}
```

#### include global/wordpress.conf;

```
#WordPress single blog rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

#A little something from the Search Overload blog entry
location = /search { 
    limit_req zone=wpsearch burst=3 nodelay;
    try_files $uri /index.php; 
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ \.php$ {

    # Zero-day exploit defense.
    # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
    # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
    # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass php;

    ##
    # Fastcgi cache
    ##
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mistake in your nginx configuration:

```
    error_page 403 = 404;
```

This causes nginx to try to redirect to a document named "404", which is exactly what is happening.

This should have been written as:

```
    error_page 403 =404;
```

Or better yet, it should not be present at all. Sending a blatantly wrong error code is a good way to confuse people (like yourself).

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I've remove the line and now I am getting a 403, but that was expected because of this rule: `if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Wget"){return 403;}` Thank you very much :-)